# One button in a .aspx page is unable to trigger onclick event

Tags: c#, asp.net

Products.aspx:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Brand"></asp:Label></td>
<td>

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1"
    runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Brand" 
    DataValueField="Brand">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HandheldConnect %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Brand] FROM [Product1]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Model"></asp:Label></td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="ModelTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Description"></asp:Label></td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="DescriptionTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" 
        Height="102px" Width="288px"></asp:TextBox></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Quantity"></asp:Label></td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="QuantityTextBox" runat="server" onkeypress="return AcceptNumericOnly(event, false);"></asp:TextBox></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Price"></asp:Label></td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="PriceTextBox" runat="server" onkeypress="return AcceptNumericOnly(event, false);"></asp:TextBox></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Image"></asp:Label></td>
<td>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="ImageUpload" runat="server" />
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Delete" />
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> 
    <asp:Label ID="StatusLabel" runat="server" Text="Status:"></asp:Label> </td>
    <td> 
        <asp:Label ID="StatusTextLabel" runat="server" Text="No operation performed"></asp:Label> </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Products.aspx.cs:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (ImageUpload.HasFile)
        {
            string str = ImageUpload.FileName;
            ImageUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(".") + "//Images/Mobiles/Samsung//" + str);
            string path = str;

            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Product1(Brand,Model,Description,Price,Image) values('" + HBrand + "','" + ModelTextBox.Text + "','" + DescriptionTextBox.Text + "','" + PriceTextBox.Text + "','" + path + "')", conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            StatusTextLabel.Text = "Uploaded" + HBrand + "product";
        }

        else
        {
            StatusTextLabel.Text = "Please Choose a file";
        }
    }
}
```

The button1_click never triggers, but the page displays "The webpage cannot be displayed". Plus what should be the map path if My files are located at "Images/Mobiles/Samsung"?

Please help

Comment: If it's displaying the error that the webpage cannot be displayed after clicking the button, then the button *is* being triggered.

Comment: Post your web.config file content please.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your button1 click event, and click the button. If it *hits* the breakpoint, this indicates your button_click is being called. Then, step through your click event, and monitor the `path` variable, see what its value is what it attempts to redirect the user.

Comment: Please inlcude your page declaration <%Page [something] %> most likely the issue is there

Comment: Maybe try the browser developer tools (F12) and sniff the connection to see if something strange happen with the postback.

Comment: "//Images/Mobiles/Samsung//", why // is not around the word Mobiles?